# They say that I am sexy - who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, lateral-thinking

Who am I?

> They say that I am sexy
> And that I'm a lady
> I have four syllables
> Only when said slowly

Hint #1

> They tend to say I am sexy more often when said quickly. But it's subjective I guess.

Hint #2

> I can influence the way you read me. (Literally)

Hint #3

> I can influence the way you pronounce me

Hint #4

> I'm considered a disorder

Comment: I wanted to say ιώτα due to the acrostic here, but even pronouncing it incorrectly only yields three syllables. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is:

> [Dyslexia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslexia)

---

"*They say that I am sexy*"

> Dyslexia can cause readers to miss the *L* and pronounce it *dy**sexi**a*.

"*And that I'm a lady*"

> Dyslexia can cause readers to mix letters completely; though this is a bit far fetched, as a mild sufferer, I can see it happening because all the letters are present.

"*I have four syllables*"

> Dyslexia has four syllables.

"*Only when said slowly*"

> A technique for managing dyslexia is to slow your reading down. Reading quickly can cause you to drop letters, syllables or even entire words.

##### Hints

> **1**: Refer back to line 1.
>  **2 & 3**: Refer back to line 2.
>  **4**: Dyslexia is a disorder characterized by difficulty reading in individuals with otherwise unaffected intelligence.

---

Further reading if you're interested:

> [Dyscalculia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyscalculia) is a disability resulting in difficulty learning or comprehending arithmetic, such as difficulty in understanding numbers, learning how to manipulate numbers, performing mathematical calculations and learning facts in mathematics.

Comment: Very well done 

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite have it all, but there's a lateral thinking tag so I'll roll with it. I think you are

> An accent

> They say that I am sexy

> A common trope is that accents are sexy

> And that I'm a lady

> 'Accent' pronounced with an accent could be heard as 'A scent' Maybe as in 'The scent of a woman'

> I have four syllables only when said slowly

> Slowed down, and accentuating each part, "Aah-cuh-sen-tah"

Hint #1

> Subjective opinion of what accents are attractive?

Hint #2

> Referring to Diacritical accents in writing

Hint #3

> Referring to Spoken Accents

Comment: I think this is it.

Comment: Really nice! not what I was going for though. I added another hint, hope you give it another go :)

Answer (score 0):

This is way out there and almost certainly not the answer. Doesn't fit with hint #2 that I can see either.

> Adora: belle (adorable). Adorable = sexy. And they say "Adora: belle" when pointing out that Adora is a belle.
> > I know, I know. I was looking for words ending in -ble (belle) or -gle (gal) or similar, that meant sexy (which can mean having sex appeal or fashionable/trendy (as in "a sexy product").

Comment: Not quite, but good try :) see hint #3